# Как получить список задач из планировщика?

Tags: python, wmi, scheduler

Python, wmi, windows
Необходимо получить список задач из планировщика задач на удаленной машине, желательно используя модуль wmi.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по информации [отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--scheduled-tasks):

```sql
Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob
```

А [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-scheduledjob) можно подсмотреть поля:

```cpp
class Win32_ScheduledJob : CIM_Job
{
  string   Caption;
  string   Description;
  datetime InstallDate;
  string   Name;
  string   Status;
  datetime ElapsedTime;
  string   Notify;
  string   Owner;
  uint32   Priority;
  datetime TimeSubmitted;
  datetime UntilTime;
  string   Command;
  uint32   DaysOfMonth;
  uint32   DaysOfWeek;
  boolean  InteractWithDesktop;
  uint32   JobId;
  string   JobStatus;
  boolean  RunRepeatedly;
  datetime StartTime;
};
```